# ColorBox - How to display div using class

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

My HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="read_more">Read More</span>
    <div class="hidden description" id="description1">Description</div>
</div>
..
<div class="parent">
    <span class="read_more">Read More</span>
    <div class="hidden description" id="description2">Description</div>
</div>
```

My Js code which works for id if I give the id to each description div's

```
$(".read_more").on("click", function (e) {
    var href = '#'+$(this).next().attr('id');
    $(this).colorbox({ inline: true, href: href });
});
```

I am using [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) plugin.

When I click on Read More I need the Description to pop up. I am able to achieve this using id and I don't want to give id's to the description as this is dynamically generated. How could I achieve this using class? Is this possible?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So what's your existing JS that works for IDs?

Comment: @VergilPenkov code updated!

Comment: Sorry but could you update the HTML as well so we can know how you're using IDs in this case? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) also accepts HTML. Try the below

```
$(".read_more").on("click", function (e) {
    var html = '#'+$(this).next().html();
    $(this).colorbox({ inline: true, html: html });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your css class 'hidden' applies display:none; try this

css:

```
.not_hidden { display:block }
```

jquery

```
$('.read_more').click(function(){ 
      $(this).next('.description').addClass('not_hidden')
})
```

edited to use classes.

Comment: OP is using `ColorBox` and your answer doesn't have it!!

Comment: 'When I click on  Read More I need the Description to pop up' with jquery tagged. I'm unable to understand why this is an invalid answer. If jquery is not allowed, why is it tagged.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I am sorry. I should have paid more attention to the documentation.

```
// Using a jQuery object:
$(".read_more").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $desc = $(this).next();
    $(this).colorbox({ inline: true, href: $desc });
});
```